# Angular / RxJS: Sending an API request then polling another endpoint

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable

I want to send an API request then poll another endpoint until a response with a `success: true` body comes back from the second endpoint. I am using Angular's HTTPClient to make my requests. My original thought was to do this:

```
createConversion(request): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('/endpoint', request).pipe(

      // This is the problem: I want to start polling before this post() call emits

      mergeMap((response) => {

        // Start polling

        return timer(0, 5000).pipe(
          takeUntil(this.converted$),
          concatMap(() => {

            return this.http.get('/second-endpoint')
          })
        )
      })
    );
```

However, the mergeMap is not called until the first `post()` call emits with the first request's response. Is there an RxJS operator that will allow me to start the polling before the first `post()` call emits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
createConversion(request): Observable<any> {
    const post$ = this.http.post('/endpoint', request).pipe(startWith(null)); 
    // force fake emission
    const get$ = this.http.get('/second-endpoint');
    const polling$ = timer(0,5000).pipe(mergeMap(_=> get$), takeUntil(this.converted$));

    return post$.pipe(mergeMap(_=> polling$));
}
```

Comment: That was it, the key was to use startWith(null) to force the first emission